# You are given a set of intervals S. You have to find all intervals in S that are contained in a given interval (a, b) in minimum time complexity

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, tree, intervals

**You are given a set of intervals `S`. You have to find all intervals in `S` that are contained in a given interval `(a, b)` in minimum time complexity.**

This can be done in `O(n)` time by brute force, where `n` is the number of intervals in set `S`. But if I am allowed to do some pre-processing, can this be done in less than `O(n)` time e.g. `O(log n)` time?

Initially I was thinking of [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), but I don't think it is applicable here because interval tree is used to get all intervals that **overlaps** with a given interval.

Comment: As stated, the best you can do is `O(n)` because, in the worst case, all elements of `S` must be copied to the output.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I was hoping for something like O(logn) + O(m), where m is the number of elements in the output.

Comment: @SteveM well note that, in terms of big O notation, `O(logn)+O(m) = O(n)`, because m can be as large as n. Pre processing time is included with the runtime as well because if you want to sort the intervals or arrange them using some data structures those are part of your algorithm too.

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/77008/55291

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remodel your problem in the 2D-plane. Let the `(begin, end)` of each interval be a two-dimensional point. (Note that all valid intervals will end up above the diagonal)

Your Interval-search-problem transforms into well-studied **orthogonal 2D range queries** with algorithms that have [image: O(sqrt(n)+k)] or [image: O(log^2+n +k)] runtime, where k is the number of points reported.

[image: range query]

Comment: Nice idea, but I am not aware of any algorithm with a complexity less than O(k) where k is the number of points reported. Thus, Patricia is right.

Comment: Yea that's true. I've updated my answer to include the description of k. But sometimes the datapoints are nicely distributed and your queries cover only a small set, so that amortized k << n.

Answer (score 1):

[Persistent binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Trees) may be used here.

**Pre-processing:**

1. Create empty persistent tree. It should store intervals sorted by their ending points.
2. Sort intervals by their starting points.
3. For each interval, starting from the end of sorted list, create a "copy" of persistent tree and add this interval to this copy.

**Search:**

1. Find starting point of the query interval in sorted list.
2. Iterate corresponding "copy" of persistent tree from the smallest key to end of the query interval.

Search time complexity is O(log(n) + m), where m is number of elements in the output.

Comment: It seems that its space complexity is O(n^2). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SteveM: Space complexity is O(n*log(n)). Persistent data structures allow to make shallow "copies" where most of the data is shared between "copies", so each BST update needs only O(log(n)) additional nodes.